# My GetSalesTax function is not returning what I need so I can display values

Tags: vb.net

This is resolved, I declared all my variables at class level and probably wrote too much code than necessary but it works. second block is updated to what worked.

I'm supposed to use a procedure to display a subtotal, and then a function to show the sales tax, and I cannot get my form to display anything except the lblSubtotal.Text. The problem comes from the requirement to show the subtotal using a procedure and that isn't going to return a value to me. So I tried parsing the text in the label and using that but this is not working. Thank you for any advice.

````
    Private Sub ShowSubtotal()
        Dim dblSubtotal As Double
        If radNone.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 2.75
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 2.75
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSalesTax(ByRef dblSub As Double) As Double 
        Dim dblSalesTax As Double                                   
        Double.TryParse(lblSubtotal.Text, dblSub)
        dblSalesTax = dblSub * 0.06

        Return dblSalesTax
    End Function
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim dblSub As Double
        Dim dblTotal As Double
        Dim dblSalesTax As Double


        Call ShowSubtotal()

        Call GetSalesTax(dblSub)
        lblTax.Text = dblSalesTax.ToString("C2")
        dblTotal = dblSub + dblSalesTax
        lblTotalDue.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")

    End Sub


**ugly working fix-** 
```Public Class frmMain
    Dim dblSubtotal As Double
    Dim dblTotal As Double
    Dim dblSalesTax As Double
    Private Sub ShowSubtotal()
        Dim dblSubtotal As Double
        If radNone.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 2.75
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.5
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 2.75
            lblSubtotal.Text = dblSubtotal.ToString("C2")
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Function GetSalesTax(ByVal dblSalesTax As Double) As Double
        Dim dblTaxRate As Double = 0.06

        If radNone.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radGlazed.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.05
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.05
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radSugar.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 2.75 + 1.05
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 1.5
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radChoc.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.25 + 2.75
        ElseIf radNone.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5
        ElseIf radRegular.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 1.5
        ElseIf radCapp.Checked And radFilled.Checked Then
            dblSubtotal = 1.5 + 2.75
        End If

        dblSalesTax = dblSubtotal * dblTaxRate
        lblTax.Text = dblSalesTax.ToString("C2")
        dblTotal = dblSubtotal + dblSalesTax
        lblTotalDue.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2")
        Return dblSalesTax
    End Function
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click


        Call ShowSubtotal()

        Call GetSalesTax(dblSalesTax)

    End Sub
````

Comment: In your ShowSubtotal() method, are any of the If conditionals actually being satisfied?  If you put a breakpoint at the top of that method and step through it what happens?

Comment: The very first condition is the default and true until a different selection is made.

Comment: Visual Studio has a quite good debugger. What happens when you use it to step through the code to see what it's doing? A debugger is the absolute best tool you have available to trace the execution path and find the errors in your logic. If you don't know how to use it, now is the perfect time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with money it is a good idea to use `Decimal` instead of `Double`.

To set up the design of your form.

Use 2 `GroupBoxes`. One for the Beverage radio buttons and one for the Donuts.

Controls have a handy property called `Tag`. You can store anything you want in the `Tag` property. For our purposes we can store the price of each radio button choice in the radio button's `Tag` property. This will greatly simplify the code.

Set one of the radio buttons in each group box to `Checked = True` so there is a default selection.

Now, on to the code.

We won't need all the form level variables. We do want to keep our number variable and our string variables for display in the labels straight. The `Call` word is only used a rare circumstances.

First, the `GetSubTotal` function is called. This function uses another function to get the selected radio button in each `GroupBox`. The `GroupBox` is passed to the function and a `RadioButton` is returned. When we get the selected `RadioButton`, its `Tag` property is retrieved for the price. We need to covert it to a `Decimal` since it is stored as an `Object`.

I think the rest is self explanatory. Ask me if it doesn't make sense. This way, you avoid a great deal of duplicate code.

```
Public Class Donuts

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim SubTotal = GetSubTotal()
        lblSubtotal.Text = SubTotal.ToString("N2")
        Dim Tax = CDec(SubTotal * 0.06)
        Tax = Decimal.Round(Tax, 2)
        lblTax.Text = Tax.ToString("N2")
        Dim Total = SubTotal + Tax
        lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString("N2")
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSubTotal() As Decimal
        Dim rbBeverage = GetSelectedRadioButton(grbBeverage)
        Dim BeverageTotal = CDec(rbBeverage.Tag)
        Dim rbDonut = GetSelectedRadioButton(grbDonut)
        Dim DonutTotal = CDec(rbDonut.Tag)
        Return BeverageTotal + DonutTotal
    End Function

    Public Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
        Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
        Return rb
    End Function

End Class
```